# DNS queries "DomainServer.dom.local.dev.null" by QNAP NAS

Tags: dns, query, qnap

We encounter strange DNS queries intiated by a QNAP NAS:

```
DomainServer.dom.local.dev.null
```

`DomainServer.dom.local` (name is obfuscated here) is the valid name of the domain controller. But the NAS adds `.dev.null` to the name.

This looks to me as if a default DNS name is configured which is added automatically. But I can not find such a setting on the NAS.

Can someone explain this?

---

**From the DNS log of the domain controller**

Devices in the log

- 192.168.0.1 = domain controller (DomainServer.dom.local)
- 192.168.0.16 = QNAP NAS
- 192.168.0.254 = Sophos UTM

---

```
15.01.2019 11:53:39 2728 PACKET  000000E796562170 UDP Rcv 192.168.0.16    4c9e   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] AAAA   (12)NameOfServer(3)dom(5)local(3)dev(4)null(0)
UDP question info at 000000E796562170
  Socket = 556
  Remote addr 192.168.0.16, port 56856
  Time Query=533586, Queued=0, Expire=0
  Buf length = 0x0fa0 (4000)
  Msg length = 0x0031 (49)
  Message:
    XID       0x4c9e
    Flags     0x0100
      QR        0 (QUESTION)
      OPCODE    0 (QUERY)
      AA        0
      TC        0
      RD        1
      RA        0
      Z         0
      CD        0
      AD        0
      RCODE     0 (NOERROR)
    QCOUNT    1
    ACOUNT    0
    NSCOUNT   0
    ARCOUNT   0
    QUESTION SECTION:
    Offset = 0x000c, RR count = 0
    Name      "(12)NameOfServer(3)dom(5)local(3)dev(4)null(0)"
      QTYPE   AAAA (28)
      QCLASS  1
    ANSWER SECTION:
      empty
    AUTHORITY SECTION:
      empty
    ADDITIONAL SECTION:
      empty

15.01.2019 11:53:39 2728 PACKET  000000E7932A4220 UDP Snd 192.168.0.254   4eb1   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] AAAA   (12)NameOfServer(3)dom(5)local(3)dev(4)null(0)
UDP question info at 000000E7932A4220
  Socket = 11688
  Remote addr 192.168.0.254, port 53
  Time Query=0, Queued=0, Expire=0
  Buf length = 0x0fa0 (4000)
  Msg length = 0x003c (60)
  Message:
    XID       0x4eb1
    Flags     0x0100
      QR        0 (QUESTION)
      OPCODE    0 (QUERY)
      AA        0
      TC        0
      RD        1
      RA        0
      Z         0
      CD        0
      AD        0
      RCODE     0 (NOERROR)
    QCOUNT    1
    ACOUNT    0
    NSCOUNT   0
    ARCOUNT   1
    QUESTION SECTION:
    Offset = 0x000c, RR count = 0
    Name      "(12)NameOfServer(3)dom(5)local(3)dev(4)null(0)"
      QTYPE   AAAA (28)
      QCLASS  1
    ANSWER SECTION:
      empty
    AUTHORITY SECTION:
      empty
    ADDITIONAL SECTION:
    Offset = 0x0031, RR count = 0
    Name      "(0)"
      TYPE   OPT  (41)
      CLASS  4000
      TTL    32768
      DLEN   0
      DATA   
        Buffer Size  = 4000
        Rcode Ext    = 0
        Rcode Full   = 0
        Version      = 0
        Flags        = 80 DO
```

---

**Edit**

- The qnap has the latest firmware installed
- We checked the config files and the gui and found no `dev/null` entry
- Not all DNS requests comming from the QNAP are containing the `.dev.null`; the most requests are regular, like: `(12)NameOfServer(3)dom(5)local(0)` => `NameOfServer.dom.local`

Comment: Are you sure that in some configuration script somewhere there isn't a miswritten `/dev/null`?

Comment: @harrymc indeed, this was my first attempt after reading "dev null". But we couldn't find any entry. Neither in the GUI nor in configs which were checked by our linux guys. (This is why it came up and we are a little woried: https://serverfault.com/questions/949361/suspicious-dns-query-leads-to-intrusion-protection-alert-on-sophos-utm)

Comment: Did you check the NAS `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: @harrymc only `nameserver 192.168.0.1` in `resolv.conf`

Comment: Is the QNAP firmware updated?

Comment: @harrymc yes, that was the first thing I did

Comment: Is a search domain Suffix entered in the network config? If nothing is configured maybe the System adds dev.null as search domain name. Just saw a post in the qnap forum that brought me to this idea...